# Mailscanner and amavisd-new comparison

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, spam, amavis, mailscanner

I'm going to implement a mailfiltering gateway for my company. I'm going to use Postfix, with a PostgreSQL back-end.

The question would be: how to best implement the antispam measures.

- Mailscanner + SpamAssassin?
- amavisd-new + SpamAssassin?

(Note: I don't need antivirus filtering)

I've been searching for up-to-date comparison between Mailscanner and amavisd-new, but most comparisons I found are severely out of date.

Can someone provide me an up-to-date comparison or a link to such?

TIA

Comment: But, consider this point of view: http://wiki.mailscanner.info/doku.php?id=documentation:configuration:mta:postfix:politics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Silly me. Just found out about this page:

http://www.postfix.org/addon.html

... and I quote:

> mailscanner system, works with Postfix and other MTAs. WARNING: This software uses unsupported methods to manipulate Postfix queue files directly. This will result in corruption or loss of mail. The mailscanner authors have sofar refused to discuss a proper access API or protocol.

Case solved. amavisd-new, it will be.

Thanks for everyone who have tried to answer!

---

***Edit:***

In the comments, @Spikolynn referred to http://wiki.mailscanner.info/doku.php?id=documentation:configuration:mta:postfix:politics , which explains how Postfix now implements a 'holding' queue which should prevent queue corruption.

Many improvements have happened on the Postfix side since this question was asked; so if you happen upon this Q&A as a result of a search, please be aware that the situation might not be as clear cut as it was when I came upon the problem.

Comment: Could you accept this as the answer to your question? Would help other visitors and keep the site clean(er).

Comment: @syneticon-dj I'd like to, but it's still under embargo (i.e., clicking on the checkmark pops up a box "You can accept your own answer tomorrow") :)

Comment: BTW, as a side note: amavisd-new is working quite well with postfix. We're using it with AV scanners enabled, although technically there hardly would ever be a need due to configurable blocking by filetype - we just block executables and whatever is currently on the "potentially harmful" list.

Comment: @syneticon-dj I had dabbled with amavisd-new before,  and honestly didn't find any grievances. However,  someone in a mailing list mentioned Mailscanner,  and that's why I asked my question.  Anyways,  thanks for sharing your experience :-)

Comment: the http://wiki.mailscanner.info/doku.php?id=documentation:configuration:mta:postfix:politics mentions a way you can configure mailscanner/postfix to not corrupt queues :)

Comment: @Spikolynn thanks! Although the question is already 3 years old, I'm sure the information there would be helpful for others facing the same situation as I was :-)  (I have changed job a couple of times, and my current employer is not using Postfix)

Comment: MailScanner is mega-awesome, but the primary maintainer has retired and it isn't getting the focus that it once did.  The complaints about postfix queue corruption are overblown.